# toggling the <ul> list on clicking a link

Tags: jquery

What I need is to toggle the ? unordered list inside  another list tag when a link inside parent unordered list is clicked. I don't want to use an id selector for this.

My HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Members</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" href="#sm"> Chit Management </a>
        <ul id="sm" class="sub-menu collapse" style="list-style:none;">
            <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" href="#sm1"> Collection Management </a>
        <ul id="sm1" class="sub-menu collapse" style="list-style:none;">
            <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" href="#sm1">Cash Book Management </a></li>
        <ul id="sm1" class="sub-menu collapse" style="list-style:none;">
            <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Create Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Reports</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: there's an extra </li> in *Cash Book Management*

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use id-selector, you can use class-selector.

**Sample** http://jsfiddle.net/npeagg4v/

Another way - just use html tags, but this is risky as u can make some changes in future and logic become broken.

```
    $('li a').unbind('click').click(function(){
       $(this).closest('li').find('ul').toggle();

       return false;
});
```

**Sample** http://jsfiddle.net/npeagg4v/1/

Link on Jquery documentation : http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ (`toggle`) and http://api.jquery.com/closest/ (`closest`)

Answer (score 0):

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mydnygk3/1/

```
$("ul a").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggleClass("collapse");
});
```

Also see :

http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

**Note** : Use class or id on click() selector to make the effect more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toggle()` function and also can add some smoothness or animation in it:

```
$("ul a").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings("ul").toggle("fast");
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mydnygk3/2/)